# Kotlin Generics - Call companion object method

Tags: android, kotlin

I've two implementation of `RecyclerView.ViewAdapter`, which are very identical and I want to unify them as a single class with a type parameter `T`. The only difference is one class uses `ImageViewHolder` and the other one `VideoViewHolder`.

```
class ImageGridAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<ImageViewHolder>() {

    private val asyncListDiffer = AsyncListDiffer<Image>(this, diffCallback)

    init { setHasStableIds(true) }

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ImageViewHolder {
        // How to call this companion object method from a generic class?
        return ImageViewHolder.from(parent)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ImageViewHolder, position: Int) {
        holder.bind(asyncListDiffer.currentList[position], dragSelector, lifecycle.get())
    }

    fun submit(list: List<Image>) = asyncListDiffer.submitList(list)

    override fun getItemCount(): Int {
        return asyncListDiffer.currentList.size
    }

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
        return asyncListDiffer.currentList[position].id
    }
}
```

**Question:** How can I call `*ViewHolder.from(parent)` in a generic way in Kotlin? I really don't want to create two separate classes just to override a single method!

Comment: What about using an interface/class, which will be implemented/extended by your 2 classes?

Comment: @Steyrix `from()` method is something which creates the instance of ViewHolder in a  static way (coming from a Java world). I can create a `MediaGridAdapter<T>` and make 2 classes extend it just to override `onCreateViewHolder()`. But what I'm looking forward to is a way by which I can eliminate the need for extending those 2 classes. :)

Comment: You cannot infer generic type in class context nor can you inherit companion object methods. Proper way to do it is implementing `getItemViewType` that resolves if item is an image/video then put a switch statement inside `onCreateViewHolder` that consumes `viewType` argument.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use composition instead of inheritance, delegating ViewHolder creation to a function passed as a constructor parameter:

```kotlin
class GenericGridAdapter<VH : ViewHolder>(private val viewHolderCreator : (ViewGroup) -> VH) : RecyclerView.Adapter<VH>() {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): VH {
        return viewHolderCreator.invoke(parent)
    }

    // Other common methods
}

// And then:

val imageGridAdapter = GenericGridAdapter { ImageViewHolder.from(it) }
val videoGridAdapter = GenericGridAdapter { VideoViewHolder.from(it) }

// or using method references:

val imageGridAdapter = GenericGridAdapter((ImageViewHolder)::from)
val videoGridAdapter = GenericGridAdapter((VideoViewHolder)::from)
```

Comment: Brilliant! Time and again when I get fixated on static inheritance, the answer has been composition :)